# Multiple models to describe a rental process in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a two-sided rental marketplace and the bookings have been described with one model. It stores all the status from renter requesting, owner accepting / rejecting, to booking finished etc.

```
create_table "bookings" do |t|
   # Storing booking time info
   t.datetime "pickup_datetime"
   t.datetime "return_datetime"
   
   # create a snapshots of the state of product at time of rental requests submission
   t.integer  "hourly_rate"
   t.integer  "weekly_rate"
   t.integer  "daily_rate"

   # storing the states
   t.datetime "requested_at"
   t.datetime "accepted_at"
   t.datetime "rejected_at"
   t.datetime "cancelled_at"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.datetime "owner_reviewed_at"
   t.datetime "renter_reviewed_at"

   t.integer "renter_id"
   t.integer "product_id"

end
```

I found it very clumsy and decided to break it down to three models

> `Rental::Intent` -> Renter's intention to make a booking. Each `intent` has_many `requests`, and the first `reuqests` that confirms will become the `booking`. `intent` stores the payment status and the rental time info so it is not duplicated in each `request` and renter only have to pay deposit once.
>
> `Rental::Request` -> the request object to different product, each has its status: e.g. cancelled, expired, accepted, rejected ..etc
>
> `Rental::Booking` -> Confirmed request becomes bookings

So I know I can summarise the ActiveRelationship with `belongs_to`, `has_many` ..etc. However, I am not sure how to describe the process within the model as described above. e.g. Requests becomes bookings when requests gets confirmed.

I am wondering what is a general approach when dealing with process like this?

Comment: A renter can make multiple requests to book the same product before the owner accepts / rejects?

Comment: yes, with a limit up to 5 for example. and requests belongs to an intent, so the timing / pricing information stays consistent.

Comment: Do multiple requests result in one booking or multiple bookings?

Comment: It results in one booking, the first request that got confirmed / accepted will become the booking, and other requests within the intent will be expired automatically.

Comment: If it results in one booking, why not keep one Request object and update it when the renter makes another request?

Comment: All requests are valid until one product owner accepts a request

Comment: Would suggest you detail your process with all the business rules/constraints involved. Your intent model is trying to solve a problem which is not defined very clearly.